# Pi 3 goes to emergency message when trying to boot from pi 2 hard drive, can I make it boot?

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 2 which I've had booting off a USB SSD hard drive for some time. Now I have bought a raspberry pi 3 and was hoping that it would be as simple as swapping the hard drive and setting the appropriate `cmdline.txt` on the SD card of the new raspberry pi. Unfortunately, the pi 3 seems to start the boot process, but ultimately stops and reports a message starting with "Welcome to emergency mode!". The exact message is the same as the one shown in the image at the bottom of this post (but this is just an image from the internet, net what's actually shown on my screen)

Here is exactly what I have done. On the pi 2 I had a large format SD card (which doesn't physically fit in the new pi 3). On this card I have set cmndline.txt to the following:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=712ae4a6-73d8-4aca-9ec6-b6e507c95f74 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait program_usb_timeout=1 max_usb_current=1
```

I have formatted my SSD USB drive and given the root partition the PARTUUID shown in the command line.

fstab on the SSD contains the following:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=d96b7723-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
#PARTUUID=d96b7723-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
PARTUUID=712ae4a6-73d8-4aca-9ec6-b6e507c95f74  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

To move to the pi 3, I have a new SD card with raspbian installed(pi 2 is also running raspbian, this is what is installed on the SSD), but have again edited the `cmdline.txt` to be the same as on the pi 2. Apart from that I have left everything the same.

In case it is relevant, during boot, I get a message:

```
a start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-d96b7723\x2d01.device/start timed out
```

This runs for 90 seconds then the boot process continues. Looking through the systemd journal I see an entry like:

```
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-d96b7723\x2d01.device
```

There are other errors after this, but I guess this is the root cause?

So, can this work, and if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my fstab still looked for the boot partition of the old SD card which was referenced by `PARTUUID=96b7723-01`. My SSD PARTUUID has not changed, but the SD card has. I changed this to `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and I can now boot as it finds the new SD card partition.